# Accessing Ruby libraries in Liquid templates, specifically Faker

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, faker

I am wondering if the Liquid templating engines allows accessing Ruby libraries in the template. I am using Jekyll to prototype Web interfaces and would like to use [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to generate realistic content e.g names etc.

I can head down the path of writing a Liquid plugin and before I do I thought I best check if there's a way to expose a Ruby library to a Liquid template.

Answer (score 1):

You can access any other module from Jekyll plugins as any other regular Ruby file, in this case there is no problem using Faker from a plugin.

For example, creating a plugin to use a tag to generate random names using Faker:

```
require 'faker'

module Jekyll

  class RandomnameTag < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
      @name = Faker::Name.name
    end

    def render(context)
      "#{@text} #{@name}"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('render_name', Jekyll::RandomnameTag)
```

Then you can use it as: `<p>{% render_name this is a faker name: %}</p>` outputting: `this is a faker name: Ulises Bergstrom`.